# How do I block the new TLD's in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, spamassasin

For the longest time it seemed like what I had in place lately worked fine to block many of these new TLD's like .shop, .online, .tech, etc. All of a sudden it seems like some are getting through and I am wondering if I have something wrong with how I am set up or if there is something else going on letting these sneak in.

Right now I have in my main.cf file

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/reject_domains reject_unknown_sender_domain reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname reject_unknown_client_hostname
```

In reject_domains I have many of the persistent TLD's listed:

```
/\.online$/ REJECT
```

However I also notice somewhere along the line I also added:

```
/^.*@google.com$/ REJECT
```

the culprit shows as this in the email headers

```
eta.sureoak.online
```

Am I daft and missing something blatant?

Edit: I have followed some instructions from a different site and with little change it is blocking the required domains again but I am more confused now as I haven't really changed any of the original stuff. I did add

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

along with a domain

```
google.com REJECT
```

Thing is I am getting the reject message from the original settings. It's working now but still really confused what the original problem was and why it's working again now.

Comment: Rather than pursue your Wack-A-Mole strategy (also known as "Allow All, but forbid this list"), could you "Forbid All, but allow this list"?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The server is essentially used for my emails only but are tied to an outward facing business. When something is rejected it does send out a message (error) that tells the user what happened and how to reach us but still has to be able to receive the vast majority of the stuff that comes in not from freemail servers.